# How to turn off Android Studio's mutli-line editing?

Tags: android-studio

Sometimes I unknowingly switch on something that could be called multi-line editing in Android Studio.

[image]

- Is that a feature or a bug?
- How so I switch it off? I always restart Android Studio to get out of that mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the key stroke as I accidentally hit it:

On Mac: Cmd + Shift + 8

[image]